# Solve $A=\text{adj}(A)$ in $\mathbf{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Solve the equation $A=\text{adj}(A)$ in $\mathbf{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$.
>
> Where $\text{adj}(A)$ is the adjugate of $A$ (tranpose of cofactor matrix).

**Here is what I know:**

- $A^2=\det(A)I_n$
- $\text{rank(A)} \lt n-1 \implies \text{rank}(\text{adj}(A)) = 0$

**Here is what I have done so far:**

We have 3 cases:

1. If $det(A) = 0$

   Then $A^2=0$, thus $\text{rank}(A)\leq2-1=1$.

   This implies $\text{rank(A)} = \text{rank}(\text{adj}(A)) \leq 1$

   So $\text{rank}(A) = 0$, that is, $A=0$
2. If $det(A) > 0$

   Then $\left(X-\sqrt{\det A}\right)\left(X+\sqrt{\det A}\right)$ has $A$ as a root.

   Thus $A$ is diagonalizable (since its minimal polynomial has simple roots) and its eigenvalues are a subset of $\{\sqrt{\det A}, -\sqrt{\det A} \}$.

   Thus $A=P^{-1}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \pm\sqrt{\det A} & &\\
   & \ddots &\\
   & & \pm\sqrt{\det A}
   \end{bmatrix}
   P$

   Which we can verify as a solution to our equation.
3. If $det(A) < 0$

   Then $A^2=\det(A)I_n$.

   Thus $B^2=-I_n$ with $B=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\det A}}A$

   How do I solve for $B$?

Comment: Any such $B$ is conjugate to a block-diagonal matrix with blocks that look like $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, so necessarily $n$ is even. In fact, such a $B$ is what is called a [complex structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure), meaning that it could be used to define a "multiplication by $i$".

Comment: $A^2=0$ does not necessarily imply $A$ has rank $1$: for example, $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ squares to $0$ and has rank $2$. But it does have rank less than $n$ (in general, at most $n/2$, actually) which is all you need, except when $n=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We consider three possibilities according to the rank of $A$:

1. $\operatorname{rank}(A)<n-1$. Then $\operatorname{adj}(A)=0$. Hence $A=0$. Clearly this is a valid solution.
2. $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n-1$. Then $\operatorname{rank}(\operatorname{adj}(A))=1$. Therefore equation $A=\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is solvable only if $n=2$. However, it is evident that the equation
   $$
   \pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}=\pmatrix{d&-b\\ -c&a}
   $$
   has not any rank-one solution.
3. $A$ is nonsingular. Since $A=\operatorname{adj}(A)$, we have
   $$
   A^2=A\operatorname{adj}(A)=\det(A)I.\tag{$\dagger$}
   $$
   Take determinants on both sides, we get $\det(A)^2=\det(A)^n$. Therefore $\det(A)=\pm1$. If $\det(A)=-1$, then $A^2+I=0$. Since $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb R$, it is the minimal polynomial of $A$ and the characteristic polynomial of $A$ must be a power of $x^2+1$. But then $\det(A)=1$, which is a contradiction. Thus $\det(A)$ must be equal to $1$ and $A^2=I$. Hence $A$ is similar to $I_{n-k}\oplus-I_k$ for some even integer $k$.

In short, $A=\operatorname{adj}(A)$ if and only if $A=0$ or $A$ is similar to $I_{n-k}\oplus-I_k$ for some even integer $k$.

Two comments to your solution attempt:

- In your first case, the condition $A^2=0$ doesn't imply that the rank of $A$ is $1$. E.g. consider $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}\oplus\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$.
- In your second case, $\det(A)$ must be equal to $1$, as shown in my answer above. The number of negative eigenvalues must also be even, as the determinant is positive.

Comment: Why is the characteristic polynomial a power of $x^2+1$, and not just a multiple?

Comment: @MathBuster The characteristic and minimal polynomials share the same irreducible factors. Therefore all irreducible factors of the characteristic poly. $p(x)$ of $A$ in this case are equal to $x^2+1$. That is, $p(x)=c(x^2+1)^m$ for some integer $m$. Since $p$ is by definition a monic poly. of degree $n$, we must have $c=1$ and $m=n/2$.

Answer (score 1):

user1551 has already posted an answer, but i would like to explain why $det(A)\geq0$ and case 3 doesnt have solutions.

Suppose $det(A)<0$
A has a negative eigenvalue k.
$Ax=kx$
$det(A)x=A^2x=k^2x$
$0>det(A)=k^2>0$
contradiction

Comment: Since we're working in $\mathbb{R}$, we have no idea if $A$ has a real eigenvalue or not.
In fact, $A$ has no real eigenvalues because $x^2+1$ has no real roots.

Comment: @MathBuster i think the non-real eigenvalues can be paired with their conjugates, so the product of all non-real ev is positive. so there must be a negative ev.